# Upload/Download files to Local Machine Network path using Jquery/HTML5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, file-upload

We have a web Application written in ASP.NET MVC 4 with a file upload functionality. It saves the file to a directory in the web server on upload and user can download it back, which worked fine.

Now our client wants all his files to be saved and retrieved to and from his local server in the LAN (\FileServer\Files) instead of hitting the web server through internet to avoid the bandwidth as their production files are big/huge upto 50 MB.

Can this be achieved using Jquery / HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

I think what will work best is to have the html/JavaScript post to an endpoint on the server that's on the LAN.

I'm not sure what you mean by "can this be achieved using jQuery/ HTML5" but the answer is no from a perspective of you can't write lines of html or JavaScript that will send the file and force the server to store it/retrieve it. You'll want an application running on that server that will do that for you and the HTML / jQuery will just post to that server.

I would also suggest building it in such a way that the LAN server or the client side code redirected you to the web server to display either a failure or success page.